# Below code is for removing dublicates in sorted linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

*The below code is for removing duplicates in the sorted linked list but my code doesn't give the right output...if the input is **247 301 443 443 450 523 588 593 839 1035 1301 1403 1493 1494 1574 1650 1720 1815 1853 1868 1917 -1** but my code gives right output for smaller inputs. where is the error in my code??*

```
public class Solution {
public static LinkedListNode<Integer> removeDuplicates(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
    LinkedListNode<Integer> t1=head;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> t2=head.next;
    if(head==null || head.next==null)
    {
        return head;
    }

    while(t2!=null)
    {
        if(t1.data==(t2.data) )
        {
            t2=t2.next;
        }
        else
        {
        t1.next=t2;
        t1=t1.next;
        t2=t2.next;
        }
    }
    t1.next=t2;
    return head;
```

}
}

Comment: use equals instead of ==

Comment: Replace `t1.data==(t2.data)` with `t1.data.equals(t2.data)`